# How to catch when an `<option>` is selected through the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, forms

I have an interface where users click on an `<option>` to select a building from a list to get more information. This triggers a DOM click event on the `<option>` which I catch to provide relevant information. Some users press <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to select an adjacent `<option>`. How can I catch this event? None of change, keypress, keydown, or focus fire.

```
var newOption = document.createElement('option');
// ....
newOption.addEventListener('change', handleMyEvent);
```

It's fine if the handler also fires when the user clicks since both should do the same thing.

Comment: Why not use the change event on the `<select>` tag instead?

Comment: `option` cannot trigger change, cause it will never change. You should monitor events on `select` element.

Comment: @AdamKonieska: It doesn't fire for me when I select an option with the keyboard.

Comment: @Charles Selecting an option with the keyboard requires you to hit enter once you are focused on the `option` you want, are you doing that? Or are you looking for catching just the movement of the selector via keyboard without selecting?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: The latter.

Comment: Add listener to change on select. I just tested in a fiddle and that fires for selection via click, enter, or arrow up and down.

Comment: It does not fire on arrow up and down, Firefox, Win 10 (and it should not, nothing changed).

Comment: @Charles I would update your question to specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach an onchange event listener to the select element

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="handleMyEvent()">
  <option value="1">Option 1
  <option value="2">Option 2
</select>
```

You can use this demo to experiment by selecting options with your keyboard at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange).

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to capture the event of moving the focus option element via the keyboard, not on a specific selection (which would require them to hit enter).

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to do this using JavaScript, so to add on to your code, the OP can fire the `onchange` listener using this: `document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange(handleMyEvent);`. But, the `GlobalEventHandlers.onchange` method isn't supported in IE8-, so you can use `document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener("change", handleMyEvent)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to detect when the user navigates to the select via the mouse or keyboard, you'd need bind the function to the focus event. Then you can get the selected option.  Something like this would work:

**HTML**

```
<select id="foo"></select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var select = document.getElementById('foo');

for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var newOption = document.createElement('option');
    newOption.innerHTML = "bar"+i;
  select.appendChild(newOption);
}




select.addEventListener('change', handleMyEvent);
select.addEventListener('focus', handleMyFocusEvent);

function handleMyEvent() {
    console.log(this.value)
}

function handleMyFocusEvent() {
    console.log('Select is focused')
    console.log(this.value)
}
```

JS Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qzkL1y7w/1/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an onKeyUp event handler as well if you want to track it as the option is cycled.  The select element still has focus and a form element is not "changed" until it loses focus (depends on browser/version).

```
var newOption = document.createElement('option');
// ....
newOption.addEventListener('change', handleMyEvent);
newOption.addEventListener('keyup', handleMyEvent);
```